# How to choose between `std::vector<char>` and `std::string`?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, stl

What aspects need to be considered when making such a choice?

My two cents about this question:

1.The `std::string` is still valid even if there is a `\0` in the middle of data stream.

2.`std::string` have many useful methods which could manipulate strings, whereas `std::vector<char>` does not provide.

3.If the data is just binary stream, it's better to choose `std::vector<char>` other than `std::string`.

Comment: If you need string functions, use a `std::string`. If you don't, don't. Related, when I need a binary stream I use neither; I use `std::vector<uint8_t>`

Comment: You can use `std::vector<std::byte>` instead of char to make it even clearer it's binary data and not text.

Comment: 2 is outdated since there is `std::string_view`.

Comment: If I'm working with text, I use `string`.  If I'm working with a buffer, I use `vector<char>` (or `vector<uint8_t>` or `vector<byte>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What aspects need to be considered when making such a choice?

What is the input data and what is it going to be used for in the future? That would be a big consideration.

If the input data is not going to be used as a string in the future, it may be clearer in the future if you used a container as specified in the comments e.g. `std::vector<std::byte>`.